# C++ inheritance of Arduino SoftwareSerial class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, arduino

I am trying to create a new class that will inherit from `SoftwareSerial` class (shown below in the code segment). When I declare the new class as `class SerialGSM : public Stream`, it compiles. But when using `class SerialGSM : public SoftwareSerial`, it fails with the message

> expected class-name before'{' token

Following is the related code segment:

```
#ifndef _SerialGSM_H
#define _SerialGSM_H
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
class SerialGSM : public SoftwareSerial {
public:
    SerialGSM(int RXPin,int TXPin);
protected:
    float payRate;
};
#endif /* not defined _SerialGSM_H */
```

Comment: This suggests that the definition of SoftwareSerial is not in the header file you have included in this file

Comment: `expected class-name before'{` : The identifier `SoftwareSerieal` is not being recognised as a type, of class type. Forward declare it in place of `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>`. Does the compiler error persist?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Added

```
 #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
```

on the pde as well.

```
#include <SerialGSM.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SerialGSM cell(2,3);
void setup(){  
 cell.begin(9600);
}
```